# POST request on Angular do not work using mySql

Tags: node.js, angular, express, post, request

I'm using Express to make the api and I'm using angular to send the POST request, for some reason the request do not send and i have no idea why.

server

```
app.post('/users/register', (req, res) => {
    const { first_name, last_name, email, password, city, street } = req.body
    pool.query('INSERT INTO users SET ? ',  {first_name,last_name,email,password,city,street }, (err, data) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(data);
            res.status(200).send(data)
        }
    })
})
```

service

```
  insertUsers(registerFrom) {
   return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/users/register', registerFrom)
  }
```

component TS

```
  submitFrom(registerForm) {
    console.log(registerForm);
     this.appControl.insertUsers(registerForm)
     .subscribe(data => {
       console.log(data);
     })
  }
```

Component html

```
        <form #registerFrom="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submitFrom(registerFrom.value)" class="form-container sign-up-container">
                <div class="thisForm">
                <h1>Create Account</h1>
                <div >
                    <input type="checkbox" id="admin" name="admin" value="Admin">
                    <label for="admin"> Admin?</label>
                </div>
                <div class="social-container">
                    <span>or use your account</span>
                </div>
                <input ngModel name="name" type="text" placeholder="First name" />
                <input ngModel name="lastName" type="text" placeholder="Last name" />
                <input ngModel name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" />
                <input ngModel name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                <div  class="adress">
                    <input name="city" ngModel type="text" placeholder="City">
                    <input name="street" ngModel type="text" placeholder="Street">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" value="Submit">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

in server use array instead of Object

```
pool.query('INSERT INTO users SET ? ',  [first_name,last_name,email,password,city,street, (err, data) => {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the query:

```
pool.query('INSERT INTO users ( first_name, last_name, email, password, city, street ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)', [first_name, last_name, email, password, city, street]), function (error, results) {
      if (error) throw error;
      // ...
    });
```

and check out the docs about escaping query values https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#escaping-query-values

> In order to avoid SQL Injection attacks, you should always escape any
>   user provided data before using it inside a SQL query